# JQuery fadeIn/fadeOut image on click jumps while loading new image

Tags: jquery

There's a gallery with a large image with thumbnails on the side. Click the thumbnail, the large image fades out, new one fades in (src getting called from the rel attribute of the link).

Problem: The old image fades out, re-appears, then jumps to the new image... I'm guessing the new image hasn't loaded yet, since it only happens the first time the image is loaded.

---

HTML

```
<div id="image"><img src="http://marilynmcaleer.com/images/BeachRoad-title.jpg" width="480" height="383" /></div>
<div id="thumbnails">
    <div class="thumbnail-homes"><a href="#" rel="http://marilynmcaleer.com/images/BeachRoad-title.jpg" class="image"><img src="http://marilynmcaleer.com/thumbnails/homeportrait_thumbs/BeachHouse_thumb.jpg" width="136" height="90" alt="Beach House" /></a></div>
    <div class="thumbnail-nudes"><a href="#" rel="http://marilynmcaleer.com/images/ReducedFigure-title.jpg" class="image"><img src="http://marilynmcaleer.com/thumbnails/nude thumbs/reducedfigure_thumb.jpg" width="136" height="90" alt="Patience" /></a></div>

    <div class="thumbnail-murals"><a href="#" rel="http://marilynmcaleer.com/images/BabyElephant-title.jpg" class="image"><img src="http://marilynmcaleer.com/thumbnails/mural thumbs/babyelephant_thumb.jpg" width="136" height="90" alt="Baby Elephant" /></a></div>
    <div class="thumbnail-paintings"><a href="#" rel="http://marilynmcaleer.com/images/Charlevox-title.jpg" class="image"><img src="http://marilynmcaleer.com/thumbnails/homeportrait_thumbs/Charlevouix_thumb.jpg" width="136" height="90" alt="Boat Shed" /></a></div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

JQuery

```
    $(function() {
        $(".image").click(function() {                  // something with class "image" gets clicked and a function happens
            var image = $(this).attr("rel");                // variable (image) is defined to be the rel attribute of the link that was clicked
            $('#image img').hide();                             // hides the old big image
            $('#image img').attr('src', image);
            $('#image img').fadeIn();                       // animate to fade in 
        return false;
    });
});
```

Live Site: http://marilynmcaleer.com/

---

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `load` event so the fade starts once the image is loaded, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $(".image").click(function() {
    var image = $(this).attr("rel");
    $('#image img').hide().one('load', function() {
      $(this).fadeIn(); 
    }).attr('src', image);
    return false;
  });
});
```

This binds the [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) handler using [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) as to not attach multiple event handlers (adding one every time), and will fade in once the image loads...make sure to set the `src` *after* binding the `load` handler so it's attached and ready to go.  Even if the image is fetched from cache, this will work.

---

Alternatively, a bit better solution if possible is to bind that handler just once, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('#image img').load(function() {
    $(this).fadeIn(); 
  });
  $(".image").click(function() {
    var image = $(this).attr("rel");
    $('#image img').stop().hide().attr('src', image);
    return false;
  });
});
```

Then every time it loads, it'll fade in again, the [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) is to handle many clicks in a row, queuing up animations.

Answer (score 0):

I always have problems with the nested elements not returning the right event target, so you might want to use live events:

```
    $(function () {
        var img = $('#image img');
        img.load(function(e) {
            img.fadeIn();
        });
        $(".thumbnails").live('click', function(e) {
            var rel = $(e.target).closest("a").attr("rel");
            img.stop().hide().attr('src', rel);
        });
    });
```